# Java servlet upload file and get post parameter

Tags: java, servlets, post

I want to upload from iphone to servlet registration data and pictures of user. Can I do that in one request or should I do two requests? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in one request. It is called multipart form. This is actually what happens when you submit form from your web browser. To save time you can use [FileUplodad](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) from Jakarta.